# How can I make this animation repeat after a period of time without using a timer

Tags: android, android-animation

I want this animation to repeat after a 30 seconds. I can use a timer and apply the animation to the view every 30 seconds but i am wondering if it is possible to do it in the xml without having to use timers

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <!-- contract -->
    <scale

        android:duration="400"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.5"
        android:toYScale="1.5" />

    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" >
        <!-- expand -->
        <scale
            android:duration="400"
            android:fillBefore="false"
            android:fromXScale="1.2"
            android:fromYScale="1.2"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="400"
            android:toXScale="0.8"
            android:toYScale="0.8" />
        <!-- spin -->
        <rotate
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="700"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:toYScale="0.0" />
    </set>

    <!-- wobble -->
    <set
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >
        <rotate
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="200"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="10%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:repeatCount="30"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"
            android:toDegrees="5" />
    </set>

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do it in the xml. And also you should not use timer for this, because it runs the code in a backround thread. What you need is android native

```
Handler#postDelayed()
```

And also do not forget to clear the animations.